# Tag <slot> cannot appear inside <table> due to HTML content restrictions. It will be hoisted out of <table> by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vuejs, While running the following code I am getting the error mentioned at the bottom. Please suggest what should I change.

```
<template>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th v-for="item in thead">
                            <div class="dataviewer-th" @click="sort(item.key)" v-if="item.sort">
                                <span>{{item.title}}</span>
                                <span v-if="params.column === item.key">
                                    <span v-if="params.direction === 'asc'">&#x25B2;</span>
                                    <span v-else>&#x25BC;</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div v-else>
                                <span>{{item.title}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <slot v-for="item in model.data" :item="item"></slot>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer pagination-footer">
            <div class="pagination-item">
                <span>Per page: </span>
                <select v-model="params.per_page" @change="fetchData">
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
   //some code
</script>
```

While running the above code I am getting the **following error**

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/components/valuechain/DataViewer.vue

  51 |                 <tbody>
  52 |                     <slot v-for="item in model.data" :item="item"></slot>
    |                     ^
  53 |                 </tbody>
```

**Tag  cannot appear inside  due to HTML content restrictions. It will be hoisted out of  by the browser**

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel or Vue: it just is a rule in plain HTML that you cannot add a custom element as a child of a `tbody` element. `tbody` should only have `tr` elements as children.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
            <tbody>
                <slot v-for="item in model.data" :item="item"></slot>
            </tbody>
```

you should use the flexibility of the tbody-tag, which may occoure 0-n times in a table. So just write

```
            <tbody v-for="item in model.data">
            </tbody>
```

or

```
        <tbody v-for="item in model.data">
          <tr><td><item-component :item="item"><item-component></td></td>
        </tbody>
```

Also you should have in mind that slot is a usecase where you want to inject html into the component IN the parent template. So slots are a chance to conditionaly override child template code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Vue.component('xc-tbody', {
       render(create) {
           return create('tbody', this.$slots.default)
       },
   })
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.